# R can not resolve to variable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to Android .I am Developing a simple registration login system.In each Class there are many same errors of each R occurrence.The Error is R can not resolve to variable.I am Posting One of Class code here

Here is my code

```
package com.UserAccounts;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUPActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword;
    Button btnCreateAccount;

    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        // Get Refferences of Views
        editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);

        btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
        btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

            // check if any of the fields are vaccant
            if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
            }
            // check if both password matches
            if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // Save the Data in Database
                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is in a different package than the app's package as declared in the manifest, you need to import your app's `R` class. The form should be

```
import your_app_package_name_as_defined_in_the_manifest.R;
```

Note that if you have errors in any of the project's resource files, the R.java file will not be generated and an `R` class won't exist. If that's the case, resolve the resource file errors and the undefined `R` class error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Check you don't have an error on your res folder and then make a Clean on your project (Project-->Clean)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the yourpackage.R then the errors will be resolved... I think it will be some thing like import com.UserAccounts.R

Answer (score 0):

first I am "import your_app_package_name_as_defined_in_the_manifest.R;" after that I press Project -> Clean, and done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Importing my own resource file into my own package is the last thing I want to do.  You should not have to 
resort to this IMO! (However, I have resorted to this before! Hypocrite!)

I've had this problem numerous times and it was caused by different things associated with my xml files.

Check:
* Do you have typos in any onCreatView() methods where you call Inflator.inflate... R.id.my_resource.xml.

*Look at the 'Design' tab in the layout editor.  Check that they all point to the same android version.  Like 23 ect.

*In the layout editor check the themes that you are using.

*Sometimes you may have an Include tag in the xml that doesn't point to another xml file to include.

*Keep looking at the xml and inflators, sometimes a given layout doesn't even seem to have a 
problem, indicated with a red line.

*Look for typos and errors in your other resource files too if you still can't rid yourself of the problem.

*You may also have to run a 'clean' each time you make a change.

*Take a break and come back to it later.